# Couroutine for-loop doesn't update text field correctly when using Yield Return New WaitForSeconds(x)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't even know WHY this is happening, but every time my coroutine for-loop runs with the "yield return new waitforseconds(x)", it adds to the text box twice.

for example

without waitforseconds

```
objects gotten:
pebble
rock
cork
apple
```

with waitforseconds

```
objects gotten:
pebble
pebble
rock
rock
cork
cork
apple
apple
```

i dont know WHY this is happening because the other things i have running in the loop dont seem to be affected **except** the text box update.

heres the code, any help would be appreciated!

```
IEnumerator ListObjects(float timing, List<GameObject> list, TextMeshProUGUI textbox)
    {
        float itemCount = list.Count;
        float timesRun = 0;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
        {
            timesRun++;
            objectCount.text = "Objects gathered: " + (i+1);
            textbox.text += "\n" + list[i].name;
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(timing);
        }
        Debug.Log(timesRun);
        yield return null;
    }
```

(the code runs when the game time is 0, so that is why im using realtime)

Comment: Looks like `ListObjects()` is being called more than once

Comment: i wish it was, but the only two references to it in the script are the first call and then the function itself

Comment: even slowing the timing down to 1s makes the script add it twice to the text box at the same time

Comment: Don't use coroutines as they teach bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that the collider on the end gate was detecting both the player and the child of the player, and running the script twice. Leaving this question up incase anyone else cant find anything like me.

Comment: So basically the very first comment on the question